# Apply a bootstrap class to my Html.DropDownListFor have made my dropdown list too huge

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, html-helper

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i wrote the following inside my razor view, where i add `form-control` class to my `Html.DropDownListFor`:-

```
<div class="form-group">
<label >Account </label> @Html.DropDownList("CustomerList", new SelectList(ViewBag.AllCustomers, "CustomerID", "Name",Model.currentfiltercustomer), "<< All Customers >>",new { @class = "form-control" } ) </div>
```

here is the markup generated :-

```
<div class="form-group">
<label >Account </label> <select class="form-control" id="CustomerList" name="CustomerList"><option value="">&lt;&lt; All Customers &gt;&gt;</option>

<option value="10">AccountTest</option>
<option value="11">Customer 200</option>
<option value="12">CustomerNew</option>
<option value="13">customerOne</option>
<option value="14">Dummy Account</option>
<option value="15">My Org Inc</option>
<option value="16">new 123</option>

<option value="18">test new account name</option>
</select> </div>
```

but the result was not very plesunt as follow, where the dropdownlist almost occupy the whole page:-

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.form-control` class has a width of 100%. You can wrap your select in a grid column to enforce the desired width. [Here's the relevant section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#column-sizing) from the Bootstrap 3 docs. Or, even easier (but less flexible), you can explicitly set the width on the element. For example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CustomerList", new SelectList(ViewBag.AllCustomers, "CustomerID", "Name",Model.currentfiltercustomer), "<< All Customers >>",new { @class = "form-control", style="width:200px" } )
```

Comment: ok thanks but not sure what do you mean by .form-control class has a width of 100% ,, because if i write the following Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) the generated text box will not occupy the whole page width ,,  so why this effect was applied to dropdownlistfor but will not have the same effect of occupying the whole page width inside the editorfor (when rendering an text box)?

Comment: Hmm .. it's hard to say without seeing your css or being able to inspect the page to determine which css rules are being applied and/or overridden.

Comment: but you mentioned that the .form-control has a width of 100% i tohugh you are talking in general..